# Django + Ajax + FormData: uploaded file is unicode array

Tags: ajax, django, polymer, form-data

I can't upload images to the server. All attributes there are until images. In request.FILES they are, but only as unicode array of file name.
And this error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

It's my view:

```
    for _f in request.FILES:
        print(_f)
        for _fi in _f:
            print(_fi)
        photo = PostPhoto.objects.create(photo = _f, name = str(_f))
        photo.save()

        destination = open('media/photos/'+str(photo.pk)+'.jpeg', 'w')
        for chunk in _f.read():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()

        print(photo)

        post.photos = photo
```

and it's js:

```
                    if (file.length <= 10) {
                        if (hasExtension(file, ['jpeg','jpg'])) {
                            console.log('files are correct');
                            var message = document.getElementById('search_textarea').value;
                            console.log('text');
                            var body_data = new FormData();
                            body_data.append('text', message);
                            body_data.append('loc_lat', elements[i].latitude);
                            body_data.append('loc_lon', elements[i].longitude);
                            body_data.append('loc_name', results[i].name);
                            body_data.append('loc_addr', results[i].formatted_address);
                            body_data.append('types', results[i].types);
                            body_data.append('action', null);
                            for(var k = 0; k <= (file.length - 1); k++) {
                                console.log(file[k]);
                                body_data.append(k, file[k], file[k].name);
                            }
                            this.$.ajaxNewPost.body = body_data;
                            this.$.ajaxNewPost.contentType = false;
                            this.$.ajaxNewPost.generateRequest();
                            console.log('ajax sended');
                        } else {
                            console.log('incorrect files');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('too match files');
                    }
```

How i can resolve it? I've tried post it via tastypie, but there i couldn't save image too, because of tastypie returned for me byte-file of this request

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
    for _f in request.FILES:
        photo = PostPhoto.objects.create(photo=_f, name=str(_f))
        photo.save()

        destination = open('media/photos/' + str(photo.pk) + '.jpeg', 'w')
        for _file in request.FILES.get(_f):
            for chunk in _file:
                destination.write(chunk)

        post.photos = photo
        destination.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `for _f in request.FILES:` _f is a unicode type what mean it's just a string.

try to use `_f = request.FILES.get('your_parameter_name')` to replace it

Comment: yes, it works, i've updated my question, maybe you can improve my code, because 4.5Mb image took near 300 ms to save

Comment: i think it may cause by your network . but is the server run in localhost?

Comment: yes, i think it maybe caused by saving file into temporary folder. My notebook is too slow for this